Publishing WPF Project using command
When publishing my WPF project i normally use Visual Studio 22 by going to "Publish Selection", plugging in my settings (win-x86, any-cpu, self-contained).
This works as expected, however i now want to automate deployment using my GitHub repository and GitHub Actions.
For that, I need a command to achieve the publishment.
After a while I ended up with this command for the job:
dotnet publish --configuration Release --self-contained true --runtime win-x86 --output ./published

However: running this (either in the GitHub Action using run: *the command* or just locally using cmd) I get the following error:

The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core
version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild

I did some digging and tried the following:
1. Modified the .csproj file
I added:
<PropertyGroup>
  <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

Which did not make a difference.
2. Used msbuild command
I swapped out the dotnet publish command with dotnet msbuild -v:normal -p:Configuration=RELEASE
which resulted in the following error when executed in the GitHub Action:
Assets file 'D:\a\SES\SES\SES\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [D:\a\SES\SES\SES\SES.csproj]

And this one again when executed locally:

The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core
version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild

The following questions arise:
1. What's the underlying problem here?
2. Why does it not fail when creating via VS
3. How do I correctly publish via a command to avoid this and to use it in my GitHub action?

Have you installed "Visual Studio 2022" or "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022" on the host for the build agent? You need to run the stand-alone msbuild that is installed with VS, and not the msbuild that is embedded in dotnet. The stand-alone msbuild supports both .Net Framework and .Net (aka .Net Core). The dotnet tool, including the embedded msbuild, only supports .Net.

I remember having issues with building CI/CD pipeline one Azure devops with WPF project. Most stable solution I got was to create a publishing profile and run it within pipeline. while it might not help you 100%,but might give you some ideas for a solution

VS uses MSBuild not .NET CLI, so you should get started from msbuild /t:publish.

Note: this is tested for .NET Framework 4.8
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Setup MSBuild
    uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1

  - name: Setup Nuget
    uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.7
   
  - name: Restore Nuget Packages
    run: nuget restore [SOLUTION_PATH]

  - name: Navigate To Workspace
    run:  cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
    
  - name: Create Build Directory
    run: mkdir Release
    
  - name: Build Libraries
    run: msbuild [SOLUTION_PATH] /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:OutDir="../Release"

and of course runner for that Github Job needs to be windows
